# C# Issue while importing Excel sheets

Tags: c#, excel

I've searched the internet for this and couldn't really find a question like it.I am coding an application that takes data from Excel and view it.
All of my tests were correct, but suddenly I found that Importing a column  that contains set of numbers in a row then letters will result in not showing the fields that contain those letters at all

```
PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
        System.Data.DataTable dtSchema = new System.Data.DataTable();

        conn.Open();
        dtSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
        string Sheet1 = dtSchema.Rows[0].Field<string>("TABLE_NAME");

        conn.Close();
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + Sheet1 + "]", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

the first dataset is the regular result

```
7841
7847s
2344
2262
7738
JD32916
JD329161
JD318161
JD31716
JD7643
JD21116
7194
```

the second dataset is the problematic result (notice that I removed the 's' from "7847s")

```
7841
7847
2344
2262
7738






7194
```

as you can see, all the fields with letters in them just disappeared,
it only happens where there are 5 or more consecutive fields with no letters in them. example (2nd number from the top contains 's' to prevent that error from happening)

Comment: Probably the values are not seen as `string`? It seems that they are somehow converted to numeric type.

Comment: any Idea how to prevent that without hard-coding the Excel?

Comment: Add `IMEX=1` to your `Extended Properties` section to treat all columns as text columns.  Without it the data type is inferred by the Jet provider (sometimes incorrectly)

Comment: D Stanley, correct , Thank you, can you post it and i will mark it as answer

Comment: D Stanley, it worked fine , but when I made the list start with 15 number first, it didn't work.

Comment: It seems like making both **HDR=NO**  and **IMEX=1** in your **Extended Properties** will fix the problem.   Thanks @DStanley

Comment: If your data does not have a header row then yes `HDR=NO` is appropriate.

Comment: how about if a data with header, what do you recommend @DStanley

Comment: @AmrAlshazli `HDR=YES`

Comment: @DStanley but it will only work on up to 8 rows, if all 8 are numbers, the problem will happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IMEX=1` in your extended properties to treat all columns as text values.  Without it, the Jet provider will infer a data type based on whatever type the majority of the values in that column is, which may not be correct.

Secondly, since your data does not have a header row, you should use `HDR=NO` in your extended properties as well.